# Set the initially visible item LazyGrid (swiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm trying to set the initially visible item LazyGrid (swiftUI)

The idea is instead of the initial value be the default (0)

[image]

the initial value became the value I chose, for instance 4

[image]

with the possibility of move the grid to 0 and to 9.

I have simple grid

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {

        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
          
            LazyHGrid(rows: [GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 200, maximum: 200))]) {
                ForEach(0 ..< 10){ val in

                    ZStack{

                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        
                        
                        Text("\(val)")
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .font(.title)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SwfitUI 2.0**

There is `ScrollViewReader` for this purpose. We give `id` for views and by scroll view proxy specify which view should be visible.

Here is a demo. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoView: View {
    let initiail: Int = 4

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            ScrollViewReader { sp in
                LazyHGrid(rows: [GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 200, maximum: 200))]) {
                    ForEach(0 ..< 10, id: \.self){ val in

                        ZStack{

                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)


                            Text("\(val)")
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .font(.title)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }.id(val)
                    }
                }.onAppear { sp.scrollTo(initiail) }
            }
        }
    }
}
```